# error explicitly setting hibernate dialect to sqlite

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sqlite

I'm working on a web application using spring and hibernate with sqlite as the database backend and I keep running into an error.  Here's the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:199)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:253)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/business-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect to use [name=SQLite, majorVersion=3]; user must register resolver or explicitly set 'hibernate.dialect'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:260)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:63)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:83)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect to use [name=SQLite, majorVersion=3]; user must register resolver or explicitly set 'hibernate.dialect'
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
    ... 43 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Now, I know that hibernate doesn't currently support sqlite, so I added a file in src/main/java/org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect. I got the file from GitHub and I know it works because I've used it in projects before.  Here it is anyways:

```
/*
* The author disclaims copyright to this source code. In place of
* a legal notice, here is a blessing:
*
* May you do good and not evil.
* May you find forgiveness for yourself and forgive others.
* May you share freely, never taking more than you give.
*
*/
package org.hibernate.dialect;

import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.VarArgsSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;

public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect {

    public SQLiteDialect() {
        registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
        registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
        registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "bigint");
        registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
        registerColumnType(Types.REAL, "real");
        registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
        registerColumnType(Types.NUMERIC, "numeric");
        registerColumnType(Types.DECIMAL, "decimal");
        registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, "char");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "varchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "date");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "time");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
        registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob");
        // registerColumnType(Types.NULL, "null");
        registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "clob");
        registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "integer");

        registerFunction("concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "", "||", ""));
        registerFunction("mod", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "?1 % ?2"));
        registerFunction("substr", new StandardSQLFunction("substr", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
        registerFunction("substring", new StandardSQLFunction("substr", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
    }

    public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * public boolean supportsInsertSelectIdentity() { return true; // As
     * specify in NHibernate dialect }
     */

    public boolean hasDataTypeInIdentityColumn() {
        return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
    }

    /*
     * public String appendIdentitySelectToInsert(String insertString) { return
     * new StringBuffer(insertString.length()+30). // As specify in NHibernate
     * dialect append(insertString). append("; "
     * ).append(getIdentitySelectString()). toString(); }
     */

    public String getIdentityColumnString() {
        // return "integer primary key autoincrement";
        return "integer";
    }

    public String getIdentitySelectString() {
        return "select last_insert_rowid()";
    }

    public boolean supportsLimit() {
        return true;
    }

    protected String getLimitString(String query, boolean hasOffset) {
        return new StringBuffer(query.length() + 20).append(query).append(hasOffset ? " limit ? offset ?" : " limit ?")
            .toString();
    }

    public boolean supportsTemporaryTables() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getCreateTemporaryTableString() {
        return "create temporary table if not exists";
    }

    public boolean dropTemporaryTableAfterUse() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean supportsCurrentTimestampSelection() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isCurrentTimestampSelectStringCallable() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getCurrentTimestampSelectString() {
        return "select current_timestamp";
    }

    public boolean supportsUnionAll() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasAlterTable() {
        return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
    }

    public boolean dropConstraints() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getAddColumnString() {
        return "add column";
    }

    public String getForUpdateString() {
        return "";
    }

    public boolean supportsOuterJoinForUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getDropForeignKeyString() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No drop foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public String getAddForeignKeyConstraintString(String constraintName,
        String [] foreignKey, String referencedTable, String [] primaryKey,
        boolean referencesPrimaryKey) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public String getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add primary key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public boolean supportsIfExistsBeforeTableName() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's my test code:

```
package metrolink.core.repositories;

import metrolink.core.repositories.jpa.JpaStopRepo;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

/**
 * Created by Scott Meyer on 10/9/14.
 */
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring/business-config.xml")
public class StopRepoTest {

    @Autowired
    private StopRepo repo;

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }

}
```

and here's the spring config file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="metrolink.core.repositories.jpa"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:test" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="metrolink.core.models.entities"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>metrolink.Metrolink</value>
                <value>metrolink.MetrolinkCalculator</value>
                <value>metrolink.Stop</value>
                <value>metrolink.StopTime</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--<tx:annotation-driven/>-->

    <!--<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>-->

        </beans>
```

Let me know if there's anything else you need and thanks in advance.